# number question

Tags: numbers

how to write, for example, "It was four or $5,000 total."  Meaning $4,000 or $5,000 total.  As a court reporter we write what they say, and people do not always speak the way it needs to be written, so...

Comment: "It was four or five thousand total."

Answer (score 1):

"It was four or five thousand dollars total."